# rtmidi library (C++) cannot find LoopBe MIDI port

Tags: c++, midi

I'm trying to use RtMIDI to handle MIDI input.
On my machine I have set up the LoopBe1 internal MIDI port.
The RtMIDI code I am using is as follows (and is basically demo code off the RtMIDI site).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <signal.h>
#include "RtMidi.h"

int main()
{
  RtMidiIn *midiin = new RtMidiIn();

  // Check available ports.
  unsigned int nPorts = midiin->getPortCount();
  if ( nPorts == 0 ) {
    std::cout << "No ports available.\n";
  }
  else std::cout << "Port(s) found.\n";
  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get the no ports available message.
The LoopBe1 port is working for other MIDI applications I have on the machine and I have another MIDI application I wrote in C# (using NAudio rather than RtMIDI) that finds the port no problem.

I've been trawling the web but cannot find a reason why.
Can any one suggest any ideas as to why RtMIDI cannot find the port?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't done what the tutorial states (hadn't read the instructions):
"In order to compile RtMidi for a specific OS and API, it is necessary to supply the appropriate preprocessor definition and library within the compiler statement: "

To do this in Windows Visual C++ Express 2010 this involved:

1. Go to PROJECT -> PROPERTIES -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor
   Then in the "preprocessor definitions" box click the drop down and click edit, then add
   (underscore undercsore)WINDOWS_MM(underscore undercsore)
2. Go to PROJECT -> PROPERTIES -> LINKER
   Then in the additional dependencies input box click the drop down and click edit, then add
   winmm.lib

It now works.